# Ember Routing with renderTemplate and setupController

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-router

I am building an Ember app to show a simple Twitter-like tagging system. When a user visits `/items`, he or she will see a list of all `items`. When the user visits `/tags`, the user will see a list of `tags` as links. When the user clicks one of these links, the user **should** be directed to `/tags/:id` and will see all `items` tagged with that specific `tag`. Then the user will be able to search/sort/manipulate the items as he/she would be able to from the `ItemsRoute`.

How can I make `TagRoute` use `ItemsController` and render the `items` template, using the tag's associated `items` as the model?

I have tried different combinations of the hooks in `TagRoute`, and I'm not able to find a recipe that works. There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding on my part.

Here is my relevant code:

**router.js.coffee**

```
App.Router.map ()->
  @resource 'items'
  @resource 'tags', ->
    @resource 'tag', path: ':tag_id'
```

**routes/tag.js.coffee**

```
App.TagRoute = Ember.Route.extend
  model: (params)->
    @get('store').find 'tag', params.tag_id
  controllerName: 'items'
  setupController: (controller, model)->
    @controllerFor('items').set('model', model.items)
  renderTemplate: ->
    @render 'items', ->
      into: 'tags'
      controller: 'items'
```

**templates/tags.hbs**

```
<ul class="tag-list">
  {{#each tag in model}}
  <li>
    {{#link-to 'tag' tag}}
      {{tag.name}}
    {{/link-to}}
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

{{outlet}}
```

**models/items.js.coffee**

```
App.Item = DS.Model.extend(
  body:       DS.attr('string')
  checked:    DS.attr('boolean')
  tags:       DS.hasMany('tag')
)
```

**models/tags.js.coffee**

```
App.Tag = DS.Model.extend(
  name:             DS.attr('string')
  taggings_count:   DS.attr('number')
  items:            DS.hasMany('item')
)
```

Currently, this give me an error:

```
Error while processing route: tag Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function () {
        return {
          into: 'tags',
          controller: 'items'
        };
      } TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'name' of function () {
        return {
          into: 'tags',
          controller: 'items'
        };
      }
```

Looking at the Ember Routes Inspector in Chrome, the `controllerName` property is the only one which overrides Ember's defaults, and Ember still tries to render a generated `tag` template.

Comment: Bidirectional has many mappings are always making things more complicated. How about linking back to items with a query param?tag. Then you could pass it to the model and show only items with that tag. No need for a tags/:id route. Just link to items with query param {tag;tagname}

Comment: Could you put this code into a JSBin?

Comment: @Gaurav I'm not sure how to do routing in a JSBin, but here is the link: [link](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zeyodabise/1/edit?html,js,output). I hope what is there is helpful. My latest idea was to have the `TagRoute` redirect to a `TagItemsRoute`, but I'm having similar problems there. For example, ember generates a `'tag/items'` template instead of using my specified `'items'` template.

Comment: @ahmed.hoban Is it possible to filter a model by an associated model, using queryParams set in the controller? I'm trying it out. My understanding was that queryParams were best used for things like filtering and sorting on a model's attributes, and that routing was best for finding models by associations.

Comment: Its transparent if your backend can process /items?tag={tag} or /items?tagId={tag.id}. This would be a filter, not an associated model. Im doing the same thing for a different case and it works like a charm. Just make tag or tagId a queryParam in your itemsController.  
queryParams: {
  page: {
   refreshModel: true
  },
Pass the tag/tagId as a queryParams in your links/ transitionTo calls and thats it. I dont think there is any drawback using a filter a like that.

Comment: @ahmed.hoban Thanks! I tried it out and it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As ahmed.hoban suggested, I have solved this using query params. This helps me avoid duplicating routes and having a tangled router. It hits the database, which is not preferable, but I'm not sure at this point if I'll make that a requirement. I have control over the full-stack, so I was able to make adjustments on the back-end to support the request.

**router.js.coffee**

```
App.Router.map ()->
  @resource 'tags', path: '/', ->
    @resource 'items'
```

**routes/tag.js.coffee** - deleted

**templates/tags.hbs**

```
<ul class="tag-list">
  {{#each tag in model}}
  <li>
    {{#link-to 'items' (query-params tag=tag.id)}}
      {{tag.name}}
    {{/link-to}}
  </li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>

{{outlet}}
```

**controllers/items.js.coffee**

```
App.ItemsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend(
  needs: 'tags'

  queryParams: ['tag']
  tag: null

  items: (->
    tag = @get 'tag'
    if tag
      @store.find 'item', tag: tag
    else
      @get 'model'
  ).property('tag', 'model')
)
```

Comment: nice. But why dont you just pass the tag to your route? It will be available in params:  
model: function(params) { this.store.find('item', params)} no need for "if tag" in your controller. If no tag is set, no tag query param is passed to the server. Then you dont need the items computed property but just the model. You can, in your route, declare queryParams and add the "refreshModel" property. Whenever a queryparam on the controller is changed, the model will be refetched automatically. Magic of ember.

Comment: So in your route:
App.ItemsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  queryParams: {
    tag: {
      refreshModel: true
    }
  },
model : function(params) {
  this.store.find('item',params);
}